# bxSlider onAfterSlide callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, bxslider

Good morning all :) I've got an issue here, which is pain in my neck for 2 days already. I'm using bxSlider for images to slide on a page and I'm calling my own function in onAfterSlide callback. Everything works fine except one thing. When I quickly switching between slides my function is being called 2-3 times(I have 3 images on page), which is not good as it returns unexpected results. I can not use newest version of bxSlider, because the markup has been changed. I think this happens, because the animation is still not finished when the onAfterSlide callback is called. 
This is how I call bxSlider:

```
$('#slider_bx').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    pause: 9000,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: false,
    prevText: '',
    nextText: '',
    autoHover: true,
    captions: false,
    pager: true,
    onBeforeSlide: function () {
        if ($('.slide_in').length) {
            $('.slide_in').hide();
        }
    },
    onAfterSlide: function () {
        if ($('.slide_in').length && $('.slide_in').is(':hidden')) {
            doCrazyStuff();
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my function:

```
function doCrazyStuff() {
    var $this = $('.slide_in');
    if ($this.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.show();
            $this.rotate({
                duration: 2000,
                angle: 90,
                animateTo: -20
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've tried to add `.stop()`, but didn't helped.

```
$this.show().stop();
$this.stop().show();
$this.stop().rotate({
    duration: 2000,
    angle: 90,
    animateTo: -20
});

$this.rotate({
    duration: 2000,
    angle: 90,
    animateTo: -20
}).stop(); // throws an error
```

Comment: I recall that jQuery has 2 different queues: one regular and one for animation. Besides, you can create multiple queue "threads".. I think the trick is there.. I'll look into it a bit later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel a timeout or make a check to see if it's running.
If you want only the last timeout to run:

```
var crazyTimeout;
function doCrazyStuff() {
    var $this = $('.slide_in');
    if ($this.length > 0) {
        if (crazyTimeout != undefined) {
            clearTimeout(crazyTimeout); // Cancel previous timeout
        }
        crazyTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            crazyTimeout = undefined;
            $this.show();
            $this.rotate({
                duration: 2000,
                angle: 90,
                animateTo: -20
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

If you want only the first timeout to run:

```
var crazyTimeout;
function doCrazyStuff() {
    var $this = $('.slide_in');
    if ($this.length > 0) {
        if (crazyTimeout != undefined) {
            return; // A timeout is still running: don't create new one
        }
        crazyTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            crazyTimeout = undefined;
            $this.show();
            $this.rotate({
                duration: 2000,
                angle: 90,
                animateTo: -20
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Well done, now it's working how I wanted it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the

`$('.slide_in').stop()`

in after slide function I hope it works, if possible try to give code in fiddle it will be easy to help.

Comment: I can add code in fiddle, but I can not include bxSlider in it. Where should I add `.stop()`? I already tried to add it to this line `$this.show();`, didn't helped and this line `$this.rotate({`, but didn't helped.

Comment: you need to add it in  onAfterSlide: function () {}

Comment: Good catch, but no luck again.

Comment: Try giving the same $('.slide_in').stop()  in onBeforeSlide:function(){} I faced these types of error because of unstopped animation. Try giving the same only in onBeforeSlide and onAfterSlide and then let me know if you are getting any errors

Comment: It doesn't gives errors and still is called 3 times. Somehow I need to stop calling `doCrazyStuff();` after the first call is made.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing your code I think the problem is not with your code : but as you have set auto to true so the plugin timer is not stopped and is sliding the images in its regular interval.
so I hope the use of stopAuto() bxSlider function in your custom function will solve the problem. and don't forget to start the auto show after you have finished doing your stuff.
thanks

Comment: There is no such function as `stopAuto()`. I have used `stopShow()` and it worked, but if call `startShow()` after my function is completed, the problem still persists. Your answer is closest solution so far, so if there will not be a better one, I will mark as accepted.

Comment: bxSlider has the public function stopAuto() as I have implemented recently it in one of my project please refer the link and view under the Public methods section: (http://bxslider.com/options) thanks

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, I'm using older version of bxslider(3.0) and `stopAuto()` function is implemented in later versions.